# There is a way to extend limit of 256 chars in extension prop?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I created a extension in B2C to hold some information and reach up the limit of 256 characters. Can I extend or there is a alternative to extension?

Documentation about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't [make it bigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-user-flow#azure-ad-b2c-configuration-limits).

You could use a StringCollection and store the information over multiple attributes.

Comment: Sorry, but I need create the extension through Microsoft Graph, and MS Graph doesn't support stringCollection data type yet.